# CN1: ios app crashes when showing picker component

Tags: codenameone

My CN1 app crashes on iOS only (not on android).
With the native sources and xcode I found the error location:

The error comes up when a form is shown which includes a Picker-component.

In xcode I found that this line in my code is causing the error:
`picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);`

#### My code:

```
private boolean setPicker() {
        picker.remove();
        picker.setSelectedString(null);
        picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
        String[] arr = RatingObject.getListAsStringArray();
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            gui_ro_Picker.setStrings(arr);
        .....
```

#### Error:

`Thread 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

Code where the error appears:

```
#ifdef NEW_CODENAME_ONE_VM
JAVA_BOOLEAN com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_instanceofObjArrayI___java_lang_Object_R_boolean(CN1_THREAD_STATE_MULTI_ARG JAVA_OBJECT n1)
{
    // second part of the expression check that this isn't a primitive array
    return n1->__codenameOneParentClsReference->isArray && cn1_array_start_offset + 100 < n1->__codenameOneParentClsReference->classId;
}
```

xcode marks explicitly the `return` line with the error

Do you have any advice on this?

#### Update:

Moving `picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);` into the constructor solved the issue.

Comment: Are you setting the array of strings before setting the Picker type? Can you post the codes related to your Picker?

Comment: No I am only setting the selected string to null, I'll try without doing this. I am re-setting the picker later, that's why I need the .remove and thought .setSelectedString(null) might be useful;

Comment: I think that's where the problem is, does it run on simulator without an error? Try wrapping that line in a try-and-catch.

Comment: I will try that! Yes indeed it works on the simulator and on Android devices like that.

Comment: Also why are you doing a picker.remove()?

Comment: I did picker.remove() before updating the picker in my first try. I removed it now, don't need it any more. However picker.setSelectedString(null) is not causing the error either! The error is now solved after I moved picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS); into the constructor of the Form-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me moving `picker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS)` into the constructor solved this issue.

Thanks for the advices!